# Python3:Passing function name as arguement

Tags: python

I am learning python oop concepts and stumbled upon below code that I am trying to write. There is a class Sort which has different methods of sorting and a generic function sort.

```
class Sort:
    def __init__(self, numlist):
        self.numlist = numlist

    def msort(self, beg, end, reverse=False): #merge sort
        if beg < end:
             mid = (beg + end)//2

             self.msort(beg, mid, reverse)
             self.msort(mid+1, end, reverse)
             self.__merge(beg, mid, end, reverse)


    def isort(self, beg, end, reverse=False): #insertion sort
        i = beg #initial index
        for key in numlist[beg+1:end+1]: #from beg+1 to end
            i = i+1 #current index in numlist
            j = i-1
            if reverse:
                while j >= beg and self.numlist[j] < key:
                    self.numlist[j+1] = self.numlist[j]
                    j = j-1
                self.numlist[j+1] = key
            else:
                while j >= beg and self.numlist[j] > key:
                    self.numlist[j+1] = self.numlist[j]
                    j = j-1
                self.numlist[j+1] = key


    def sort(self, beg, end, func=msort, reverse=False):
        print('Calling {0}()'.format(func))
        func(self, beg, end, reverse)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    numlist = [3, 4, 2, 5, 9, 7, 1, 6]
    s = Sort(numlist)
    s.sort(0, len(numlist)-1, func=isort, reverse=False)
    print(s.numlist, end='')
```

I have following questions -
1. In main, if I just call s.sort(0, len(numlist)-1, reverse=False) it properly calls msort and gives the result but if I call like s.sort(0, len(numlist)-1, func=isort, reverse=False) it gives below error -

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "Sort.py", line 76, in
>   
>       s.sort(0, len(numlist)-1, func=isort, reverse=False) NameError: name 'isort' is not defined

I understand why it doesn't work but not able understand why msort works fine.

2. If I call  s.sort(0, len(numlist)-1, func=s.isort, reverse=False)
   then I get below error -

> Calling main.Sort object at
>   0x031BF830>>() Traceback (most recent call last):   File "Sort.py",
>   line 76, in 
>       s.sort(0, len(numlist)-1, func=s.isort, reverse=False)   File "Sort.py", line 71, in sort
>       func(self, beg, end, reverse) TypeError: isort() takes from 3 to 4 positional arguments but 5 were given

Not able to understand what is happening here. I seems to call isort but why is the parameter mismatch

3. In function sort(), I am not able to call self.func() which again gives attribute error. Is this a bad practice to use self. while calling other function but calling func() without using self.func()?

Please explain pythonic way of organizing this class and function calling.

Comment: be sure to copy your code exactly as it is, including indentation -- Your `def msort` line should be indented forward 4 spaces into the `Sort` class or you'll have an `IndentationError` when you try to run this

Comment: This is your first question; welcome to Stackoverflow!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your error is that `isort` is an instance method, which means it does not exist outside the scope of the `Sort` class. You can reference it by using `Sort.isort` in your `main`:

```
s.sort(0, len(numlist)-1, func=Sort.isort, reverse=False)
```

The reason you got the second error is that `s.isort` already adds `self` (where `self` is `s`) to `isort`'s argument list. When you call `func(self, ...)` you are adding `self` a second time and so you get a total of 5 arguments.

Answer (score 0):

`msort` is resolved within the scope of the class definition so it knows it is `Sort.msort`.

To use `isort` from outside of defining the class you need to use pass `Sort.isort`.

When you pass `s.isort` the method is already bound to the object, so you mustn't pass `self` as the first parameter.

Answer (score 0):

You should change you line `func(self, beg, end, reverse)` to `func(beg, end, reverse)`. The self argument is passed automagicly. I'm able to get it working with s.isort.

Comment: You would need `self.func(beg, end, reverse)` in that case, or it will look for the globally-scoped function `func`.

Comment: @Robert it won't look for the global `func`.

Comment: I tried using self.func(beg, end, reverse) but it did not work no matter how I passed func value -

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for replying. Few things are clear to me. I also found one mistake in above program that in isort function I am using

> for key in numlist[beg+1:end+1]:

which actually should be

> for key in self.numlist[beg+1:end+1]:

I will summarize the findings below -
1. Calling func(self, beg, end, reverse) works if I pass func=Sort.isort in **main**
2. Calling func(beg, end, reverse) works If I pass func=s.isort in **main**

I understood above 2 points well.

3. Calling func(beg, end, reverse) doesn't work if I pass func=Sort.isort in **main**. It gives me error -

> Calling () Traceback (most recent
>   call last):   File "Sort.py", line 79, in 
>       s1.sort(0, len(numlist)-1, func=Sort.isort, reverse=False)   File "Sort.py", line 72, in sort
>       func(beg, end, reverse)   File "Sort.py", line 55, in isort
>       for key in self.numlist[beg+1:end+1]: #from beg+1 to end AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'numlist'

I am guessing if self is not first arguement then by default 'int' object is passed in isort. So its cribbing as int doesn't have attribute numlist.

4. Calling self.func(beg, end, reverse) never works no matter how I pass func in main. I tried func=Sort.isort and func=s.isort in **main** but everytime same attribute error saying

> AttributeError: 'Sort' object has no attribute 'func'

Could anyone please confirm my findings?